Left adjoint functor between categories of polygons?

EDIT: Based on very helpful comments from Alec Rhea and Qiaochu Yuan I am adding some specification on objects and morphisms, hoping that this clarifies the idea behind these categories. I have also reflected these comments in the actual question.
I am constructing two categories, $\bf\mbox{ T-Poly}$ and $\bf Poly$, and a forgetful functor $U:\bf\mbox{ T-Poly}\longrightarrow{\bf Poly}$. If size issues do not stand in the way, these categories are groupoids (I have looked up several definitions of groupoids, and it seems they all assume small categories; which I am not sure about for $\bf\mbox{ T-Poly}$ and $\bf Poly$)
The category $\bf\mbox{ T-Poly}$ has finite disjoint unions of triangulated, labelled polygons as objects; labelled with three colours. These polygons are meant to be "rubber sheet" polygons, i.e. you can stretch and change angles. See the example in the first diagram.
The morphisms are breaking the polygons down into smaller ones (the "cut" respects the triangulation); or translating or rotating them;  or gluing them together (along common edges) into larger ones. The only operation that is not admissible is "flipping" the objects, i.e. changing their orientation. I have added two diagrams at the bottom to clarify my idea behind it with two more examples $h\circ g\circ f: C\rightarrow E$ and $q\circ p: C\rightarrow E$. Maybe the last example is the most important one, as it clarifies how broad the definition of morphisms is meant to be.
These morphisms compose, and the identity morphism leaves everything unchanged. Every morphism is an isomorphism. Another way of thinking about these morphisms, they define an equivalence relation among the objects.
The idea of disjoint union is important here - if $f$ breaks down a polygon $A$ into smaller ones, then $B=f(A)$ is the disjoint union of the smaller ones. (This is the two-dimensional case; it can be generalized to $n$ dimensions. I should add, this is the non-oriented case; you can extend it to the oriented case.)
I am constructing $\bf\mbox{ T-Poly}$ because I feel it is a helpful tool to study some combinatorial questions. For example, you can define a simple boundary parity functor (parity of 2-coloured boundary edges) $Par:\bf\mbox{ T-Poly}\longrightarrow \bf Z_2$. This functor gives a one-line proof of Sperner's Lemma. I will give details of that below.

The second category $\bf Poly$ has disjoint unions of labelled polygons as objects; labelled with three colours. See the example in the second diagram. The morphisms are breaking the polygons down into smaller ones (through adding corresponding edges - I have coloured these added edges in red in the diagram); translating or rotation them; or gluing them together (along common edges) into larger polygons. Again, every morphism is an isomorphism. As before, the idea of disjoint union is critical here (and you can generalize this category to $n$ dimensions and to the oriented case.)

The forgetful functor $U:\bf\mbox{ T-Poly}\longrightarrow{\bf Poly}$ is simply forgetting the triangulation inside the polygon(s), but it keeps the labelling on the boundary. In fact, whenever a polygon is broken into smaller pieces, $U(f)$ adds the same edges that $f:A\rightarrow B$ was adding. And it removes the common edges when smaller polygons are glued together along common edges into a larger one. I hope the third diagram can clarify what I mean by that. This diagram also shows that $U$ is not faithfull.

What could be the left adjoint of $U$? Based on the helpful comments from Alex Rhea and Qiaochu Yuan, the left adjoint might not exist at all. Because (if size issues do not stand in the way?), $\bf\mbox{ T-Poly}$ and ${\bf Poly}$ could be groupoids. A left adjoint to $U$ would require them to be equivalent, which is not the case. So I feel my questions might come down to a question of size.

Maybe it is helpful for the understanding of these categories if I add the following comment: a critical property of these categories is that the morphisms preserve the "parity of the boundary". Let me make this more precise for $\mbox{ T-Poly}$:
Take any 2-coloured edge on the boundary of $A$, for example $[yg] := $ the edge with a yellow and a green vertex. Any morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ in $\mbox{ T-Poly}$ adds or removes pairs of edges, so the parity of $[yg]$-edges on the boundary is the same for $A$ and $B$. Another observation is that the parity of the $[yg]$-edges is in fact the same as for the other 2-coloured edges.
This allows you to define the "boundary parity functor" $Par:\bf\mbox{ T-Poly}\longrightarrow \bf Z_2$ which expresses odd parity as $1$ and even parity as $0$. For $f: A\rightarrow B$ define
$$Par:\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
A\mapsto (\sum\, [yg] \mbox {-edges on boundaries of $A$}) \mbox{ mod } 2 \\
\\
f\mapsto \mbox{id}_{\bf Z_2}\\
\\
B\mapsto (\sum\, [yg] \mbox {-edges on boundaries of $B$}) \mbox{ mod } 2
\end{array}\right.$$
This functoriality reduces the proof of Sperner's Lemma to one line. Recall that Sperner's labelling conditions ensure that the boundary of the triangle $A$ in his Lemma has odd parity. Now simply apply a morphism $f$ that breaks the triangle $A$ down into a disjount union $B$ of all the simplices of the triangulation: To keep odd parity, $B$ must contain a 3-coloured simplex (or any odd number of them), because the simplices with 2 colours all have even boundary parity.



Very cool question and construction -- a small note, both ${\bf T-Poly}$ and ${\bf Poly}$ are groupoids so you may want to refer to them as such.

Have you tried sending them back with all triangle diagonals facing the same direction?

I don't think you want all morphisms to be isomorphisms. A functor between groupoids has a left or right adjoint iff it's an equivalence (since all natural transformations between such functors are necessarily natural isomorphisms). So if you want interesting adjoints you have to have non-invertible morphisms.

I am unable to extract a precise definition of a category out of what you've written so far. Can you describe the automorphism group of any object? Since you have a groupoid it is determined by the automorphism groups of every isomorphism class of object. For example do rotations of a square with all colors the same count as nontrivial automorphisms? If I cut a polygon into two pieces and reassemble it in a different way into a congruent polygon (again let's assume all colors are the same) does that count as a nontrivial automorphism?

@QiaochuYuan I believe composition of cuttings is given by cutting up cuts and rearranging the resulting disjoint sum of disjoint sums to be some appropriately defined disjoint sum, while composition of gluings is obvious as are identities. I don’t believe rotations are allowed. Cutting and regluing into a different shape should just provide an isomorphism bewteen the two different shaped polygons, not an automorphism (unless I miss something). Although maybe you meant it would be an automorphism of isomorphism classes?

@Alec: I am asking whether it is an automorphism (this is why I said "into a congruent polygon"); part of the question is I don't understand which objects are being considered to be the same (not just isomorphic). Explicitly (I am ignoring colors throughout), take a $2 \times 1$ rectangle, cut it into two squares, then glue them back into a rectangle but along a different edge. 1) Is this an automorphism (are the source and target considered the same object)? 2) Is this a nontrivial automorphism (is it considered different from the identity)?

If you're right that rotations aren't allowed (I can't tell either way) then these are not just free-floating abstract polygons but are, say, embedded in the plane and allowed to translate freely. If that's the case the OP should specify this, and then it raises the question of which gluings are allowed, since some gluings may require rotating the pieces. Do we only perform gluings that can be done using translation? There are many details like this that have not been specified!

And, again: if it's obvious to you that this is a precisely defined category then please tell me the automorphism group of any nontrivial object!

@Claus I am impressed by the short proof of Sperner lemma. In my point of view, if it makes Sperner lemma proof that short and simple, it means T-Poly is a worthwhile framework for study, let me give it a thought. Also, what could be the analogue of Sperner lemma in Poly.

@QiaochuYuan It seems to me that the automorphism group of each nontrivial object is the trivial group, as this is a thin groupoid. But maybe I'm understanding Claus incorrectly.

@AlecRhea Thanks a lot for your comments, really helpful. Your idea about sending them back with all triangle diagonals facing the same direction is very valuable: I am starting to think, for sending back, I should try to construct 1 object (of T-Poly) in a canonical way rather than "all possible" objects. Thanks also for the groupoid comment. I have to read a bit more about thin groupoids.

@QiaochuYuan Thanks a lot for your comments and the suggestions to specify the symmetries. I will edit my answer in the next few days (traveling right now) to clarify that. The short version is: all translations and rotations are allowed. The one thing that is not allowed: change of orientation in the sense of mirror symmetry ("flippinig it"). I am a little bit on the fence with this decision; but for now, I exclude that as I want to have the same morphisms in the oriented and non-oriented case; and for the oriented case, changing orientation would create some "damage" in my category.

@QiaochuYuan Your comment that a functor between groupoids has a left or right adjoint iff it's an equivalence: I think this gives the answer to my question, provided that size issues do not stand in the way (?).  As I mention in my edit, if there are no size issues, my category constructions are indeed groupoids, and the answer follows from your comment; I would be happy to accept it as an answer.

+1 really good construction, and love it how it applies to Sperner's lemma

I think very few category theorists would think of smallness as an essential part of the definition of “groupoid”.  Some sources consider just small groupoids, just like some sources consider just small categories — and it’s perhaps somewhat more common with groupoids, since they’re used less often as organising theatres (a big reason why large categories are important in practice) and slightly more often as combinatorial objects.  But the main definition of “groupoid” is “a category with all maps invertible”, and Qiaochu’s observation about adjoints clearly holds regardless of size issues.
